# Sybase jtds driver trying to connect to sql server

Tags: sql-server, database-connection, sybase

I have a scenario where user provides me with hostname, port and credentials for the database he wants to connect to. I do not know the flavor of the database though. So what I try to do is try connecting to each of the database types and see if the connection is successful. 
I use `sqljdbc4.jar` for sql server and `jtds-1.2.7.jar` for sybase connections. I use their respective driver urls and class names.
When I try connecting to a sybase database, the below code tries connecting to sql server first and then sybase. However when it tries the sql server connection, I see the following message repeatedly before connection fails. How can I get rid of this error message?
When I use the same hostname, port and credentials against the oracle driver details - I see an error immediately. But with sql server details it tries multiple times repeatedly. This is causing a time lag and so I want to avoid it and see the error immediately.

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection Prelogin
WARNING: ConnectionID:1 Prelogin error: host sybasehost port 4100 Unexpected response type:0
```

code:

```
try{
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        url = "jdbc:sqlserver://sybasehost:4100;databaseName=dbname";
        System.out.println(url);
        java.sql.Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "username", "password");
        System.out.println("Connection successful!");
    }
    catch(SQLException se)
    {
        se.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Connection unsuccessful");
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe)
    {
        cnfe.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Class not found");
    }
    //then try sybase db connection
    try{
        Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
        url = "jdbc:jtds:sybase://sybasehost:4100/dbname";
        System.out.println(url);
        java.sql.Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "username", "password");
        System.out.println("Connection successful!");
    }
    catch(SQLException se)
    {
        se.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Connection unsuccessful");
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe)
    {
        cnfe.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Class not found");
    }
```